# Alternatives to createRealmObjectSchema, removed in version 3.5.0

Tags: java, android, realm

Is there any way to Initialise a whole entity during a migration. I mean, a complex class that I want to fully declare instead of manually `.addField` multiple times.

In *Realm Java* version *3.4.0* I've been successfully using the method `createRealmObjectSchema` of the generated `RealmProxy` classes.

For example, if I have a class named `NewBigEntityClass` with many fields, and possible relations to *sub entities*

Then I wrote a migration like that

```
if (oldVersion <= 2) {
     NewBigEntityClassRealmProxy.createRealmObjectSchema(dynamicRealm.getSchema());
}
```

This created the whole schema and *sub entities* too, but now that's been removed in version 3.5.0 of *Realm*.

Does anybody know for an alternative? Please, don't answer with just do it field by field, as that's precisely what I'm trying to avoid.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The scope of this method has been changed in this PR https://github.com/realm/realm-java/pull/4674/files#diff-36f5b86acab52385e590ad92a6d7a80cL609 also it was renamed into `createExpectedObjectSchemaInfo`

Comment: Methods in `RealmObjectProxy` class are for internal use only. I am sorry but the suggested way to do it is field by field... However this will be improved by supporting automatical migration in the near future. See https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/2530

Comment: Hi @beeender, the problem is that I'm not requesting for **automatic** migrations, but just the possibility of fully declare a new table for backing up a totally new Entity.

Comment: Hi @beeender, the problem is that I'm not requesting for **automatic** migrations, but just the possibility of fully declare a new table for backing up a totally new Entity.

The lack of this capability makes very too verbose the addition of new entities if I have to do it field by field.

For single added/removed fields, I'm doing it manually one by one already, but when I create a whole new class I don't want to add all the boilerplate code for the Schema Addition.

Probably there could be a public method in entity OsObjectSchemaInfo that created the whole entity to the RealmSchema?

Comment: The difficulty is Realm can only give you the schema info about the current version. Let's say you add a model `Foo` at version 1, then removed one field of `Foo` at version 2. When running the app at schema version 2, you will get a schema of `Foo` version 2 at the `version == 1` block. This would be quite confusing code and not quite easy to maintain. realm-java will implement something similar as the realm-cocoa which is described here https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#performing-a-migration. that would make the migration much easier for your case.

Comment: Yeah, I already was handling some *ugly* code for that reason, that's right... Any hint about a possible version of release? Is it scheduled already?